# Navigation component - how to check whether the fragment is newly navigated to vs. poped back to

Tags: android, android-navigation

When using the Navigation component, it is simple to navigate to the next fragment and also simple to pop back to the previous fragment.

```
Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(R.id.action1);
/*vs*/
Navigation.findNavController(v).popBackStack();
```

How can I check within `onViewCreated()` how startDestination / topLevel destination fragments were reached? If it was poped back to I want to run different code compared to when it was newly navigated to.

---

**Update** thanks to @Thracian for the suggestions:

I tested:

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            Log.d("MAIN", "New destination ID: " + destination.getDisplayName());
        }
    });
```

But it returns the same result, whether I directly navigate to a fragment or use popBack/navigateUp, so it does not help to distinguish.

I tested:

```
navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    navHostManager = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
    navHostManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            int backStackEntryCount = navHostManager.getBackStackEntryCount();
            int fragmentCount = navHostManager.getFragments().size();

            Log.e("MAIN","backStackEntryCount: "+backStackEntryCount+", fragmentCount: " + fragmentCount);
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately the fragment I try to solve this for is the startDestination. Hence the `backStackEntryCount` is always 0 when I reach it, both for navigateTo and for navigateUp ...

For my other top-level destinations this does also not properly work, as they always show `backStackEntryCount = 1` independent of how I reach them.

Comment: What "different code" are you trying to run? How does that code differ from other cases that cause your fragment's view to be recreated (such as configuration changes)?

Comment: For example different MotionLayout transitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the issue.

Thanks to @Thracian to pointing me towards `navHostManager.getBackStackEntryCount()` and the two Listeners that were crucial for debugging.

I solved it now via overriding `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry() == null ||
            navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry() == null ||
            navController.getCurrentBackStackEntry()
                    .getDestination().getId() == R.id.nav_dashboardFragment)
        Log.d("MAIN", "back pressed on Dashboard");
    else {
        Log.d("MAIN", "Back pressed. Target: " + navController.getPreviousBackStackEntry().getDestination().getDisplayName());

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DashboardFragment.KEY_CANCEL_ANIMATION_ID, 1);
        if (navHostManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1)
            navController.navigateUp();
        else
            navController.navigate(R.id.nav_dashboardFragment, args,
                    new NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.nav_dashboardFragment, true).build());
    }
}
```

I first check whether I am already on the start destination. If not I check whether `getBackStackEntryCount() > 1` to understand whether the next pop back would be the start destination or not. If the next would be the start destination I do not call `navigateUp()` but instead a direct navigate() with an argument that tells the fragment and most important `NavOptions` that clear the backstack to not double the startDestination in the back stack (didn't work without the NavOptions).

In the Fragment I then added:

```
    if (getArguments() != null && getArguments().get(KEY_CANCEL_ANIMATION_ID) != null) {
        Log.d("DashV", "cancel animation detected");
        motionLayout.setProgress(1);
    }
```

To cancel the animation in case the argument is found.

Answer (score 2):

You can use addOnBackstackChangeListener on childManager on NavHostFragment and check backEntryCount and compare it with a value you stored in a field.

For a FragmentContainerView in Activity with id `nav_host_fragment`

```
 <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />
```

You can get the `fragmentManager` with

```
   val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    val fragmentManager = navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager
```

And listen backStackEntryCount change with each navigation action.

```
    fragmentManager?.addOnBackStackChangedListener {
        val backStackEntryCount = fragmentManager.backStackEntryCount
        val fragmentCount = fragmentManager.fragments.size

        Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "backStackEntryCount: $backStackEntryCount, fragmentCount: $fragmentCount",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
```

You can also check out current destination id, or store them in a field if you need them.

```
   findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        .addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->

            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Destination: ${destination.id}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show()
        }
```

And to access these data from any fragment use a ViewModel that is common to Activity and fragments and set values in Activity and listen in fragments.

Comment: Hi @Thracian, thanks for your suggestions. Unfortunately they didn't solve my problem yet. Could you have a look at my updates where I describe why both options do not work yet?

Comment: Thanks for your effort and pointing me in the right direction. I'll award the bounty once the 24h timer is through.